# eclipse how to import java types quickly in javadoc comment links?

Tags: eclipse, types, import, comments, javadoc

In eclipse java editor, how to import java types quickly in javadoc comment links?
for example,

```
{@linkplain Foo}
{@linkplain Foo#do(String)}
@see Foo
@see Foo#do(String)
```

In java code, the editor will underline unknown types, and I can press CTRL+1 to import the java types.  But it did not work to types in javadoc comment.

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will execute the *Organize Imports* command which should add the imports for you. It will prompt you if there is any ambiguity about which classes to import.